# use parameters in routes definition in sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I've been trying for hours and still got no way to configure my routes the way I want to.

What I want to achieve is:

http://fooo.bar/prefix1234

I want to capture everything that starts with specifix prefix.

Pretty easy:

```
get "/prefix:id" do
 puts params[:id]
end
```

But I don't want it to be a fixed prefix. I want to put the prefix in a config file

settings.rb:
set :prefix, 'pre'

```
get "/#{settings.prefix}:id" do
 puts params[:id]
end
```

this won't work (undefined method `prefix' for Sinatra::Application:Class (NoMethodError)). I also tried capturing with regex:

```
before do
 @prefix = settings.prefix
end

get %r{#{@prefix}(\d+)} do |id| 
 puts "Params:  #{id}"
end
```

This doesn't work either (URL will not be captured)

Anyone got anything?

Comment: If in Sinatra routes are processed the same way as in rails (top to bottom) you can define route like `/*` as the last one that will match anything.

Comment: That is also not the solution I am looking for, because I want to process URLs with a prefix differently than any other URL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The String/Regexp is generated right away. This works:

```
require 'sinatra'
set :prefix, '/foo'

get "#{settings.prefix}/bar" do
  request.path_info
end
```

Comment: I tried it and it works. However I'm pretty sure I tried that before... strange

Comment: OK I'm sorry, I remember what the problem was: with this code, all my tests run fine, but when I start the application, I get the following error: undefined method `prefix' for Sinatra::Application:Class (NoMethodError)

Comment: As stated in the Sinatra ticket: You have to set that setting *before* loading the routes.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get your example working almost without modification.  This allowed me to do what you described:

```
before do
  @prefix = "test"
end

get %r{#{@prefix}(\d+)} do |c|
  puts "#{@prefix} #{c}"
  erb :test, :locals => {:id => c}
end
```

I then ran shotgun to test the output and called /test123.  The output was:

test 123

My view also reiterated that this was working properly.  If the problem is that the URL is not being captured, you may need to reorganize your structure so that it is more like:

```
before do
  @prefix = "test"
end

get "/#{@prefix}/:id" do
  puts "#{@prefix} #{params[:id]}"
  erb :test, :locals => {:id => params[:id]}
end
```

I don't know if the latter is feasible for your application, but if you are not specific enough in the routing, you are leaving yourself open for frequent bad matches.  In my experience, the more RESTful your application is, the better off you will be when it comes time to writing these types of operations.

Alternatively, perhaps a YAML file to store your settings in, and then parsed by a script would give you better results for the route.  For example, a YAML file with these contents:

```
prefix: test
```

And then a helper script that parses that, which would look something like this:

```
helpers do
  def config
    @config = YAML.load_file("config.yml")
  end
end
```

You could then replace your before block with this:

```
before do
  @prefix = config["prefix"]
end
```

My coding tastes make me lean toward using the YAML method, but I think any of these solutions should be viable.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. However only the first one is feasible and unfortunately this one is not working (completely). yes if you do da get "/test123" the URL will be captured. But when you do a  get "/something123" the URL will also be captured. It seems to me, that the variable @prefix is always empty in the routes